# new page properties not available for modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, sitepages

We have a sharepoint online 2019 as part of our O365.
I am trying to build a wiki following this example:
https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-build-an-awesome-knowledge-base-wiki-in-sharepoint-online-using-modern-pages/

However, any new properties I make do not show up in the page properties webpart.
Additionally, if I make a new property and set that as required, classic pages will force me to set the property but for modern pages I am not forced to set the property. Even more, I can not even set the property.......

What is going on here?

Thanks for thinking with me

Comment: This could help you. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/using-custom-properties-in-modern-site-pages/m-p/268006